# How to accurately get the width of a drawn String (in pixel) with Codename One?

Tags: drawing, codenameone

I am trying to place precisely a short text over an image in Codename One. I compute the location where the text should start based on the its width so that it appears centered.

However the text width that I get from

```
myFont.stringWidth(myStringToMeasure);
```

is always much greater than the actual drawn text (a rectangle is drawn around the Graphics where the text is drawn). Thus the text does not look centered at all. Here is what I get from the simulator.

[image: Part of the background image with the text over it (simulator)]

I tried to sum the width of each char within myString with

```
for (char c : myString.toCharArray()) {
     stringWidth += myFont.charWidth(c);
}
```

but the result was even larger that the previous one (nearly twice as big).

Did I misused the stringWidth method ? Is there a way to reliably get the width of a drawn string ?

*NB : I just tried it on a device and the text looked as expected. Was I just lucky or it will work on other real devices ?*

EDIT 1:

That's weird, I know @Shai is right but I can't get it working! If I just drop in his code snippet in my method I get completely different result :

```
    // width and height are the Graphics width and height that
    // has been created via Image.createImage(myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight())
    public void paintOnBackground(Graphics g, 
        int width, int height) {

     Font myFont = g.getFont();
        g.setFont(myFont);
        int w = myFont.stringWidth("Hi World");
        int h = myFont.getHeight();

        // Added just to see the background
        g.setColor(0x0000FF);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g.setColor(0xff0000);
        // Because g.getTranslateX() is equivalent to getX() (not available here)
        int x = g.getTranslateX() + width / 2 - w / 2;
        int y = g.getTranslateY() + height / 2 - h / 2;

        // The rectangle is centered
        g.drawRect(x, y, w, h, 20); // large thickness to see it at a glance!
        // The string is outside the rectangle
        g.drawString("Hi World", x, y);
```

I don't even get @Shai's result :

[image: Generated image that reflects what is on the simulator's screen (the grey background comes from Gimp)]

Any idea what I did wrong ?

EDIT 2: OK if I test it on the device (Android 4.4) the string appears as in Shai's screen capture. **So it looks like it is a problem related rather to the simulator  (all skins / Linux / Eclipse 4.5)! Shai's code (and mine also indeed) is working well on the real device.**

*EDIT 3: Problem solved : Upgrading project libs from 114 to 115 fixed the issue => see [this other SO question which was related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986722/why-do-i-get-a-different-behviour-in-codename-one-simulator-than-on-a-real-andro)*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Char width will be inaccurate by definition as chars might be drawn differently individually.

String width should be perfectly accurate everywhere when using the same Font object:

```
Form f = new Form("Width", new BorderLayout());
f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Component() {

    @Override
    protected void initComponent() {
        super.initComponent(); 
        setUIID("Label");
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Font myFont = getStyle().getFont();
        g.setFont(myFont);
        int w = myFont.stringWidth("Hi World");
        int h = myFont.getHeight();
        g.setColor(0xff0000);
        int x = getX() + getWidth() / 2 - w / 2;
        int y = getY() + getHeight() / 2 - h / 2;
        g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
        g.drawString("Hi World", x, y);
    }

});
f.show();
```

[image]

And with a different font...

```
@Override
protected void initComponent() {
    super.initComponent(); 
    setUIID("Label");
    Font handleeFont = Font.createTrueTypeFont("Handlee", "Handlee-Regular.ttf").
                    derive(Font.getDefaultFont().getHeight(), Font.STYLE_PLAIN);
    Font handleeFontLarge = handleeFont.derive(handleeFont.getHeight() * 1.5f, Font.STYLE_PLAIN);
    getUnselectedStyle().setFont(handleeFontLarge);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shai. I am using the same font object, but I create ttf font like `Font font = Font.createTrueTypeFont(myFontFeatures.get("FontName_Name"), myFontFeatures.get("FontName_Name") + ".ttf").derive(fontSize, styleName);` . Could it be the reason why I get different result than yours ? I'll check if I did a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Shai, I tried your first snippet in my code. And even with that I get different result (see my edit)! I may have changed something somewhere that leads to  this behaviour ... but I don't know what!

Comment: Did you get your screen capture from a real device @Shai ? Because for me it is working as expected on my device. It looks like the behaviour I depicted only appeared on the simulator (all skins).

Comment: The screenshot is from the Simulator using the Handlee font from the kitchen sink demo

Comment: OK so what could cause my simulator to have different results than yours and what appears on the real device ? Maybe something is wrongly configured on my simulator or Eclipse ?

Comment: Did you try my test case? Not yours?

Comment: If I try exactly yours in the beforeMain() method I get the same results as yours. Nevertheless my code behaves differently in the simulator than on the real device. Maybe it is worth opening a specific question! Thanks anyway!